# SQL Server 2008 - Function error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am new to sql programming; trying to develop this function to get rows of clients who have a specific number of visits from a view:

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_NumberOfVisit] 
(
@nv int
)
RETURNS varchar(500)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ret varchar(500)

 select *
from (
    select 
        *,
        rn = row_number() over (partition by ClientId order by VisitId)
    from
        Visit
) activityWithRn
inner join vw_MasterView on  vw_MasterView.VisitId = activityWithRn.VisitId
where activityWithRn.rn =@nv

RETURN @ret

END
```

I get the following error:

```
   Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client
```

I would appreciate your support.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of `set @var = (select` you might use `select @var = ...`.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović that won't help. The subquery uses SELECT * which is going to be more than one column, which also can't be assigned to a variable - and even if it were just one column, it would still be some arbitrary row from a multi-row result. Too many other problems to list in a comment, too.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes I know. As Answers were already posted, and they correct original misconception OP had, I was pointing out that it is not necessary to do `set ... select` because you can easily select only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that your subquery is returning too many rows.  You need to return only one row is you are assigning the result to a variable.

Change

```
set @Count = ( select *
from (
    select 
        *,
        rn = row_number() over (partition by ClientId order by VisitId)
    from
        Visit
```

To

```
set @Count = ( select count(*)
from (
    select 
        *,
        rn = row_number() over (partition by ClientId order by VisitId)
    from
        Visit
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
set @Count = ( select *
from (
    select 
        *,
```

@Count is expecting a number - you're giving it a bunch of rows, try:

```
set @Count = ( select Count(*)
from (
    select
```

Comment: +1 The OP also `RETURNS int` but actual return variable is `nvarchar(50)`

Comment: thanks I am trying to test it in a query using dbo.fn_NumberOfVisit(3) but it doesn't work

Comment: When I use Count(*) I get the number of rows; I need to display the contents of theses rows.  Thanks

Comment: @Count is an int scalar value - you can't stuff rows into it - update your question with an English description of what you want to happen (e.g. I want to count non-empty rows)

Comment: Thanks, I changed my question

Comment: @user373721 you shouldn't have changed the question so much, instead you should post another question with your new problem